# an equivalent definition of a simplex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

let $$D=\{(t_1,\cdots,t_d)\, |\, 0<t_1\leq t_2\leq \cdots \leq t_d<1  \}$$
why this is a simplex of dimension $d$ with some faces excluded? what are the excluded faces?

Comment: Write down the definitions, draw some pictures and think a bit... How do you define a simplex usually? Can you *write down* what a face is in this usual picture? If so, *which* faces don't show up here? That shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Theo Buehler: I think there are two faces excluded the face $t_1=0$ and $t_d=1$ is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $\Delta^{d} = \{  (x_1, \dots, x_{d+1}) \in \mathbb R^{d+1} \;|\; \sum_{k=1}^{d+1} x_k = 1 \text{ and } 0 \leq x_1, \dots, x_{d+1} \leq 1 \}$ is probably the definition of a $d$-dimensional simplex you know.

.

> Let $t_i := \sum_{k=1}^{i} x_k$ for $1 \leq i \leq d+1$. We now have $0 \leq t_1 \leq \dots \leq t_d \leq t_{d+1} = 1$. Thus the faces defined by $x_1=0$ and $x_{d+1} = 0$ are excluded from $D$.

Comment: So much for the attempt to induce palio to think...

Comment: Ok, I've hidden my answer, I hope this will help :D

Comment: Barely, I guess...

Comment: Well I've started writing my answer, before you got palio involved. I was disrupted for some time and didn't check for updates before submitting. I'm sorry to have disrupted your more pedagogically meaningful approach to answer his question. If you want I can still delete my answer...

Comment: No need to apologize or delete your question. Answering questions is what this site is for, after all :) Sorry about the temporary downvote.

Comment: @ Alexander Thumm: I think there are two faces excluded the face $t_1=0$ and $t_d=1$ is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Theo Buehler: Yes, that is what this site is for, and I interrupted your approach of doing so...

@palio: Yes. Can you locate these faces in dimensions $1,2,3$ ?